# JQuery Hiding Parent Divs That Aren't Already Hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use JQuery to filter the contents of a page. The page displays classes that are for several different subjects that also have attributes of school grades (Kindergarten, Elementary, Middle, and High).

Originally, I only needed to filter by the subject, but I now need to implement a way to filter by grade.

Here is my Codepin: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Omejdv

I quite easily was able to display/hide by div class "grade" with the following JQuery:

```
var $btns = $('.btn').click(function() {
  if (this.id == 'all') {
    $('#parent > div').fadeIn(450);
  } else {
    var $el = $('.' + this.id).fadeIn(450);
    $('#parent > div').not($el).hide();
  }
  $btns.removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

However, my attempt to add a "grade" filter re-shows all grade items without keeping the previously selected "subject."

Comment: should this `this.id == 'all')` not be `this.id == 'all-grades')` check it here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YVorzx

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I've done a lot of random tests to try and get this working and ultimately pasted the simplest code into a Codepin. I made the change, but it didn't affect the result. It probably did need to be changed, but it isn't all.

Comment: Sorry but im not sure what it is you want.

Comment: is this what you want? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jmjGQP

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen YES! I think that is it! I'm testing it through every scenario I can think of, and I believe it is going to work! Please post an "official" answer so I can mark it as correct!

Comment: That code is vastly different than my own! (:blush:) Thank you so much

Comment: Your welcome, happy to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed your code to fix the problem

```js
$('.btn, .grade-sel').click(function() {
  var c = $(this).attr("class");
  $("." + c).removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  var id = $("button.active").map(function() {
    return $(this).attr("id");
  });
  console.clear();
  if ($.inArray("all-grades", id) > -1 && $.inArray("all", id) > -1) {
    $("#parent div").show()
  } else if ($.inArray("all-grades", id) > -1) {
    $("#parent div:not(." + id[0] + ")").hide();
    $("#parent div." + id[0]).show();
  } else if ($.inArray("all", id) > -1) {
    $("#parent div:not(." + id[1] + ")").hide();
    $("#parent div." + id[1]).show();
  } else {

    $("#parent div:not(." + id[0] + "." + id[1] + ")").hide();
    $("#parent div." + id[0] + "." + id[1]).show();
  }

})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ecf0f1;
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.btn {
  border: none;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 5px;
}

.grade-sel {
  border: none;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 5px;
}

.active {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.box {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: calc(25% - 10px);
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #fff;
}

.spacer {
  clear: both;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="active btn" id="all">Show All</button>
<button class="btn" id="math">Math</button>
<button class="btn" id="science">Science</button>
<button class="btn" id="history">History</button>
<button class="btn" id="english">English</button>

<div class="spacer"></div>

<button class="active grade-sel" id="all-grades">All Grades</button>
<button class="grade-sel" id="kinder">Kindergarten</button>
<button class="grade-sel" id="elementary">Elementary</button>
<button class="grade-sel" id="middle">Middle</button>
<button class="grade-sel" id="high">High</button>
<div class="spacer"></div>

<div id="parent">
  <div class="box math science kinder elementary middle high">Math and science K-12</div>
  <div class="box science kinder">Kindergarten science</div>
  <div class="box math high">High School math</div>
  <div class="box history high">High School History</div>
  <div class="box english middle">Middle english</div>
  <div class="box math english elementary">Elementary Math & English</div>
  <div class="box history english kinder">Kindergarten History & english</div>
  <div class="box english science middle high">Middle & High english & science</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much!